# Recursive to non recursive function

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x=1 \\
f(x-1)+1 & \frac{f(x-1)}{x-1} < p \\
f(x-1) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Where $p$ is a constant less that or equal to 1.
And x is a whole number greater than 0.

How do I get a non recursive solution for $f(x)$?

Comment: Have you tried picking a value of $p$, calculating $f$ for $x$ in some range, then looking for a pattern in the result, trying to generalize, trying to prove the pattern persists?

Comment: I know that the patters approaches to $$ f(x)=x*p$$ for p<=1

Comment: sorry for that. I redefined the function.

Comment: Well, if you know that, then you have the answer to your question, don't you? You have a non-recursive formula for $f$.

Comment: I needed an exact one. I need to find in which case an x takes of the three. Should I reformulate the question?

Comment: If I get an exact formula I could find which case it will use myself

Comment: Well, I've given you something to try. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Nithin's answer more precise, we have
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\left\lceil (x-1) p \right\rceil & \text{ if } p \leq 1 \\
x - 1 & \text{ if } p > 1
\end{cases}$$

You can easily prove that by induction on $x$:

- If $x = 1$, then $f(x) = 0 = x-1 = \left\lceil (x-1)p \right\rceil$.
- If $p > 1$ and $f(x-1) = x - 2$, then we have $\frac{f(x-1)}{x-1} < p$, so we have $f(x) = x-2 + 1 = x-1$.
- If $p \leq 1$ and $f(x-1) = \left\lceil(x-2)p\right\rceil$, then there are two cases:

  - If $\frac{f(x-1)}{x-1} < p$, then we have $\left\lceil(x-2)p\right\rceil < (x-1)p$. Thus we have $f(x) = f(x-1)+1 = \left\lceil(x-1)p\right\rceil$.
  - Otherwise, we have $\left\lceil(x-2)p\right\rceil < (x-1)p$. So we have $f(x) = f(x-1) = \left\lceil(x-1)p\right\rceil$.